# Simpler way to check if multiple variables exist?

Tags: python, variables, exception

I know a way how to check if one variable exists:

```
try:
    my_var
except NameError:
    # not exist
```

I need to check for existence of many variables and make an action only if all of them exist. Writing a chain of `try..except` or wrapping a few `try..except`'s one around another looks rather ugly. Is there any nice way to check many vars?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to check this? As a programmer, you write the code that defines variables. You should **know** when they exist.

Comment: The solution is not to use "variable variables" in the first place. Use a _dictionary_.

Comment: @Sören I wanted to extend a function in a library that is in use in 3rd party projects to which I might have no access and I wanted to avoid code duplication. Maybe you're right and duplicating some code will cause less pain.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way around, you can check the return value of `dir()`. `sets` might come in handy.

```
a = 1
b = 2
d = 3

set_vars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'} # declare the variable names to check for
set_vars_exist = set_vars.intersection(set(dir()))
all_vars_exist = set_vars_exist == set_vars

print(all_vars_exist)
# False, because c is missing
```

Be aware that there might be some pathological edge case (depending on the output of `dir()`) where this code fails.